# perl CGI radio_group: populate values from DB query

Tags: mysql, perl, cgi, radio-group

Im trying to dynmically generate a table that has a radio button per row whose value is set to the ID field of a SQL table.  Im not sure how I can reference this value using CGI radio_group. In my research radio_group uses an associate array, however if I convert the SQL query to an associative array the values wont match up since there are more than 2 tables in the query.  If possible I'd like to avoid a second SQL call:

```
use CGI;
use DateTime::Format::MySQL;

$epoch = DateTime->now(time_zone=>"America/New_York");
$fmtnow = DateTime::Format::MySQL->format_datetime($epoch);
$iasql = qq { select * from alert where endtime > '$fmtnow'};
$iaqry = $iadb->prepare($iasql);
$iaqry->execute() || die "Fail $DBI::errstr"
print $query->start_table({-border=>1, -cellpadding =>1});
while(@iarows = $iaqry->fetchrow_array()) {
    print $query->Tr(print $query->td([print $query->radio_group('iaselect',\@iarows[0]),'@iarows[1]','@iarows[2]','@iarows[3]','@iarows[4]','@iarows[5]']));
}
print $query->end_table();
```

Comment: Sorry, that code does not compile. The problem description is also difficult to understand. Please explain what is »ID« and what you mean exactly »reference the value«. Please provide a minimal but **complete** program that works with `use strict; use warnings;`, describe the relevant part of your database schema/table structure, and supply some example data which ends up in `@iarows`.

Comment: `use strict; use warnings;` please. And whatever happened to placeholders?

Comment: I don't know what you're doing wrong, but let me suggest that you don't use the HTML generation routines in CGI. They tend to get in the way and generally be annoying. If you only need a simple HTML output, use "here documents". If you need a lot of fancy stuff, the Template Toolkit is a very well tried and tested solution.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I think Im gonna nix the the CGI radio button method for this part and just have it print `print "<input type="radio">;`, it works that way.  I was only attempting to use this method because I hadn't realized there are start_div and end_div methods. Prior to finding those I thought this was my only way of achieving the radio buttons inside of the q->div() container.

I excluded the Div portion of the code because it didn't seem relevent.